# How do I find the volume of the object bounded by?

Tags: geometry

How do I find the volume of the object bounded by

$$y^2+z^2=5x, \qquad x=2, \qquad y^2+z^2=10y$$

I can find volume when the interval of change of each variable is known. But here the equations include the other variables and it becomes messy

Comment: It is supposed to be slightly more complicated than the case where the limits are independent of other variables. What have you tried so far?

Comment: it is a lot more complicated. I tried changing to cylindrical coordinates x=x, y=rcost; z=rsint; But I cannot determine the range of the angle t.

Comment: Don't do cylindrical. Stay in Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute a multi-variable integral over non-trivial shapes, the first thing one should do is forget about the limits. One should concentrate on figuring out what the underlying domain of integration looks like. This will guild you to pick
the right change of coordinates and if you do it right, the limits will follow.

For the problem at hand, the condition $y^2 + z^2 = 2y$ is equivalent to $(y-1)^2 + z^2 = 1$. This is the equation for a circle in $yz$-plane centered at $(1,0)$ with radius $1$.

This suggests us to first change coordinate to $(y,z) = (u+1,v)$. In this coordinates, the desired volume $V$ is given by the integral:
$$V = \int_{u^2+v^2\le 1} \int_0^{(u+1)^2+v^2} dx dudv
= \int_{u^2+v^2\le 1} (u+1)^2 + v^2 dudv
$$
Notice the domain $u^2 + v^2 \le 1$ is invariant under $u \mapsto -u$ but the linear term $u$ in the integrand picks up a minus sign. This means this linear term won't contribute to the integral. We can forget it and get

$$V = \int_{u^2+v^2 \le 1} u^2 + v^2 + 1 dudv$$

Since the integration domain is a circle in $uv$-plane and the integrand
is invariant under rotation, the correct thing to do is
change variable again to polar coordinates $(u,v) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$.
This leads to

$$V = \int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} (r^2+1) r d\theta dr
= 2\pi \int_0^1 r^3 + r dr = 2\pi\left(\frac14 + \frac12 \right) = \frac{3\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: @OmniaBonaBonis The first $\int_{u^2+v^2\le 1} \cdots dudv$ stands for a double integral over a $2$-dim domain. Only when you express it as an iterated double integral, you need two $\int$. If you don't like that, you can replace every appearance of $\int_{u^2+v^2\le 1}\cdots dudv$ by $\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-v^2}}^{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \dots dudv$, the argument remains the same.

Comment: If you are referring to $\int_{u^2+v^2\le 1} \int_0^{(u+1)^2+v^2}dx du dv$, it is not a double integral, it is a triple integral, the outer one is double integral over a circle in $uv$-space. its integrand is a single integral for $x$ over $[0,(u+1)^2+v^2]$.